# Updating SQL Server using ADODB recordset UpdateBatch method

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ado

I am trying to populate a single column temporary table in SQL Server using ADO in Excel VBA.  My code is very slow, namely 145 seconds for 1,000 rows.

Is there a faster way involving maintainable elegant code that doesn't involve manipulating raw SQL strings?  I like .AddNew and .UpdateBatch...
Failing that, what is the fastest way?

```
Private Sub StackOverflowPopTempTable(cn As ADODB.Connection)

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim row As Long
Dim strSql As String
Dim row_count As Long
Dim t As Single
t = Timer

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
'Create a temporary table
strSql = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tbl_dummy_data', 'U') IS NOT NULL " & _
            "DROP TABLE ##tbl_dummy_data; " & _
            "CREATE TABLE ##tbl_dummy_data ( " & _
            "dummy_data VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY " & _
            ");"
cn.Execute strSql

'Add masterkeys to this exclusion table
strSql = "SELECT * FROM ##tbl_dummy_data"
rs.Open strSql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic


row_count = 1000
For row = 1 To row_count
    rs.AddNew
    rs("dummy_data") = "a" & row
Next row
Debug.Print Timer - t
rs.UpdateBatch
Set rs = Nothing

Debug.Print Timer - t
    
End Sub
```

Up to the UpdateBatch statement only takes half a second.  The remaining 2 minutes or so is the UpdateBatch statement.

Many thanks - I will update with anything I find in the meantime...

**Update 1**

This takes the same amount of time

```
cn.BeginTrans
row_count = 1000
For row = 1 To row_count
    strSql = "INSERT INTO ##tbl_dummy_data VALUES ('a" & row & "')"
    cn.Execute strSql
Next row
Debug.Print Timer - t
cn.CommitTrans
Debug.Print Timer - t`
```

**Update 2**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tbl_dummy_data', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##tbl_dummy_data;
CREATE TABLE ##tbl_dummy_data (
    dummy_data VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);

Insert Into ##tbl_dummy_data
    Select Cast(rand(checksum(newid()))*1000000  as int);
go 1000
```

This takes 2 minutes on the server side

**Update 3**

This takes a fraction of a second, so I suspect VBA is doing individual transactions?  Even when I use .BeginTrans and .CommitTrans?

```
DECLARE @counter INT 
        
SET @counter = 0 
BEGIN TRANSACTION
WHILE @counter < 1000
BEGIN 
   Insert Into ##tbl_dummy_data
    Select Cast(rand(checksum(newid()))*1000000  as int);
   SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Update 4**

Checked that the provider supports transactions.  It apparently does!

```
?cn.Properties("Transaction DDL").Value
 8
```

Comment: adOpenKeyset is much slower (434 seconds)

Comment: The updatebatch takes  ~0.125 secs on my desktop (SQLserver express local server), even 50,000 records only  takes 6 seconds. Time it without a primary key. Note you only need 1 line `rs.AddNew "dummy_data", "a" & row`

Comment: Removing the primary key takes longer (150 secs).  I'm going to investigate how long it takes on the server side and if it's faster in pyodbc in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer (although it is v hacky) appears to be to put all the INSERTs into one string.  This takes 1 second

```
Private Sub StackOverflowPopTempTableRaw(cn As ADODB.Connection)
    Dim row As Long
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim row_count As Long
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer

    'Create a temporary table
    strSql = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tbl_dummy_data', 'U') IS NOT NULL " & _
                "DROP TABLE ##tbl_dummy_data; " & _
                "CREATE TABLE ##tbl_dummy_data ( " & _
                "dummy_data VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY " & _
                ");"
    cn.Execute strSql
    
    'Add masterkeys to this exclusion table
    row_count = 1000
    For row = 1 To row_count
        strSql = strSql & "INSERT INTO ##tbl_dummy_data VALUES ('a" & row & "'); "
    Next row
    cn.Execute strSql
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```